# What would be Postgres equivalent of this T-SQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to run this either interactively from psql or from code.

```
create proc recent_orders_by_region
as

    select top(3) * from view_orders where region = 'NA' order by order_date desc
    select top(3) * from view_orders where  region = 'WE' order by order_date desc
    select top(3) * from view_orders where  region = 'EE' order by order_date desc
```

Comment: What would this even do in tsql? A procedure that has three select statements exactly the same with no `;` or set operator between them? Error out? Can you explain more about what you want this to do so we can help you get there? It's not at all clear.

Comment: I want to get 3 datasets, each with the most recent orders from each region.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank() over ()` but remember that order must be unique, otherwise RANK will assign the same number to multiple rows in group.

Query with example data

```sql
SELECT a.* FROM (
        SELECT *, 
        rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY region
            ORDER BY order_date DESC,ident DESC
        )
        FROM (
            values 
             (1, current_date, 'NA'),(2, current_date-1, 'NA'),
             (3, current_date-1, 'NA'),(4, current_date-4, 'NA'),
             (5, current_date, 'NA1'),(6, current_date-1, 'NA1'),
             (7, current_date-1, 'NA1'),(8, current_date-4, 'NA1')          
        ) view_orders (ident, order_date, region)
    ) a WHERE RANK <=3
```

`ident` is only for demonstration purposes and should be replaced by real column from `view_orders` table